# Update TableViewCell with Asynchronous data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a tableViewCell that contains 8 images total divided into two blocks (4 images in each block). These images are downloaded asynchronously and stored into an array and then used in the the tableViewCell's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to populate the images. I reload the tableView when all the images for one block has been added to the array in the dictionary (groupTOImages). The way I am doing it, I am getting out of order inconsistent results with the loading of the data. Some images are loaded into places where they shouldn't be. Is there a way to download the images and get consistent results in the tableViewCell.

```
var groupNames = [NSManagedObject]()
var groupTOPeople = [NSManagedObject: [String]]()
var groupTOImages = [NSManagedObject: [UIImage]]()
func getGroups() {
     ...
     for group in groupNames {
            groupTOImages[group] = []
            if let people = groupTOPeople[group] {
                var mycount = 0
            for peeps in people {
                InstagramEngine.sharedEngine().getUserDetails(peeps, withSuccess: { user in
                    if let ppic = user.profilePictureURL {
                        let picUrl = ppic.absoluteString
                        print(picUrl)
                        ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(picUrl) { (image, url) -> () in
                            self.groupTOImages[group]?.append(image!)
                            mycount++
                            if mycount == people.count {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()

                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.groupTOImages[group]?.append(UIImage())
                        mycount++
                        if mycount == people.count {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }


                    }, failure: nil )
            }
        }

        }

var counter = 0
var groupCount = 0
var groupCounter = 0
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellInfo = GroupCellsArray[indexPath.section]
     ...
     case .userGroups:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellInfo.description, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupTableViewCell
            if groupNames.count > 0 {
                var gp = groupNames[groupCounter]
                switch counter {
                    case 0:
                        cell.firstTitle.text = (gp.valueForKey("name") as! String)
                        if let ourImages = groupTOImages[gp] {
                        for image in ourImages {
                            print(image.description)
                            print("groupCount \(groupCounter)")
                            cell.firstUserButtons[groupCount].layer.borderWidth = 0
                            cell.firstUserButtons[groupCount].setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                            groupCount++
                            if groupCount == ourImages.count {
                                groupCount = 0
                                counter++
                                groupCounter++
                                gp = groupNames[groupCounter]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    case 1:
                    if let title = gp.valueForKey("name") as? String {
                        cell.secondTitle.text = title
                        if let ourImages = groupTOImages[gp] {
                            for image in ourImages {
                                cell.secondUserButtons[groupCount].layer.borderWidth = 0
                                cell.secondUserButtons[groupCount].setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                                groupCount++
                                if groupCount == ourImages.count {
                                    groupCount = 0
                                    counter = 0
                                    groupCounter++
                                    gp = groupNames[groupCounter]
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        cell.secondTitle.text = "Title"
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
```

Each row looks like the picture below:
[image]

Code using ImageLoader in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
var counter = 0
        for group in groupNames {
            print("in the second")
            groupTOImages[group] = []
            if let people = groupTOPeople[group] {
                var mycount = 0
            for peeps in people {
                InstagramEngine.sharedEngine().getUserDetails(peeps, withSuccess: { user in
                    if let ppic = user.profilePictureURL {
                        let picUrl = ppic.absoluteString
                        self.groupTOImages[group]?.append(picUrl)
                        counter++
                        mycount++
                        if counter == self.groupNames.count && mycount == people.count
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        self.groupTOImages[group]?.append(nil)
                        counter++
                        mycount++
                        if counter == self.groupNames.count && mycount == people.count
                        {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }, failure: nil )
            }
        }


 if groupNames.count > 0 {
                var gp = groupNames[groupCounter]
                print("counter!!!!")
                print("groupCount \(counter)")
                switch counter {
                    case 0:
                        if let ourImages = groupTOImages[gp] {
                            cell.firstTitle.text = (gp.valueForKey("name") as! String)
                            print(cell.firstTitle.text)
                            for image in ourImages {
                                if let url = image {
                                    print("I get in here")
                                    ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(url) { (image, url) -> () in
                                    cell.firstUserButtons[self.groupCount].layer.borderWidth = 0
                                    cell.firstUserButtons[self.groupCount].setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                                        self.groupCount++
                                        if self.groupCount == ourImages.count {
                                            self.groupCount = 0
                                            self.counter++
                                            self.groupCounter++
                                            gp = self.groupNames[self.groupCounter]
                                        }
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    self.groupCount++
                                    if self.groupCount == ourImages.count {
                                        self.groupCount = 0
                                        self.counter++
                                        self.groupCounter++
                                        gp = self.groupNames[self.groupCounter]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                case 1:
                    if let title = gp.valueForKey("name") as? String {
                        cell.secondTitle.text = title
                        if let ourImages = groupTOImages[gp] {
                            for image in ourImages {
                                if let url = image {
                                    ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(url) { (image, url) -> () in
                                    cell.secondUserButtons[self.groupCount].layer.borderWidth = 0
                                    cell.secondUserButtons[self.groupCount].setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
                                    self.groupCount++
                                        if self.groupCount == ourImages.count {
                                            self.groupCount = 0
                                            self.counter++
                                            self.groupCounter++
                                            gp = self.groupNames[self.groupCounter]
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    self.groupCount++
                                    if self.groupCount == ourImages.count {
                                        self.groupCount = 0
                                        self.counter = 0
                                        self.groupCounter++
                                        gp = self.groupNames[self.groupCounter]
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } else {
                        cell.secondTitle.text = "Title"
                    }
```

Comment: Did u call your `reloadData()` in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`? If yes, its probably just the poor handing of reuse the `tableView`

Comment: @Tj3n I have `reloadData()` called in the ImageLoader completion closure to ensure that that tableview only reloads when all images have been loaded for a block. Where would `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` come into play?

Comment: U must call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` whenever u want to work with UI stuff, u call it whenever got anything related to UI need to update like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() {self.tableView.reloadData()}`

Comment: @Tj3n Okay, but i'm not sure where to place that. At the end of the `getGroups()` function, inside the ImageLoader closure, etc?

Comment: yes, just repace the whole `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() {self.tableView.reloadData()}` with your normal `self.tableView.reloadData()` anywhere inside closure then done :D u can write that anywhere inside another closure to make sure the UI run in main thread

Comment: @Tj3n That seems to work! Thank you.

Comment: @Tj3n Actually the more I run this, it looks like i'm getting the same inconsistency. I think it may have to do with how i've setup handling  each block within each tableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I haven't come up with an elegant solution to update each block.

Comment: U mean the picture show in where they shouldnt be when u drag the tableView around? Or it lagged then replace itself with another pic?

Comment: @Tj3n Some times it runs and the images end up in the same place. Other times it runs the images end up in a different place. I've updated the original post to show what each tableView row would look like. Each one of those circles has a different image, 4 circles makes a block.

Comment: Means each cell of yours have 8 picture? i dont really understand what u mean with block

Comment: @Tj3n yes that's right. `firstUserButtons` is a UICollection of UIButton for the left 4 images and `secondUserButtons` is a UICollection of UIButton for the right 4 images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99082/discussion-between-tj3n-and-wxcoder).

Comment: @Tj3n I was able to get it working with the SDWebImage API. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `self.tableView.reloadData()` with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Hope this helps!